# Can I customise permissions granted by Dataplex "Data Roles"?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-dataplex

I'm using Dataplex to grant users permissions to underlying BigQuery tables.

This is done using Dataplex ["data roles"](https://cloud.google.com/dataplex/docs/lake-security#data-roles), which grant some (not very clearly specified?) permissions on the BigQuery tables. For example, `roles/dataplex.dataWriter` gives some vague "write" permissions to users.

Is it possible to customise which permissions Dataplex will give to a user who is assigned this role, or will I just have to manage the permissions outside of Dataplex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've spoken to Google Support and there is no way to customise the permissions that Dataplex gives on underlying resources at this time. There *is* a long-term plan for this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The role that is granted on the BigQuery dataset is roles/dataplex.storageDataWriter which contains permissions related to writing data into BigQuery.

Can you describe which permissions you would like to be granted on the Dataset, when you grant a principal the roles/dataplex.dataWriter role?